# Why do I not have access to these Properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having an issue passing properties from one class to another. 
I'm getting an error saying that an object reference is required for all of the Game properties in the second class. They are highlighted at the bottom.
this is my first class (Game):

```
 class Game
        {


  private string verb= "";
            private string noun= "";
            private string adjective= "";
            private string panimal= "";
            private string pnoun= "";


            public string Verb
                {
                get {return verb; }
                set {verb = value; }
                }    
            public string Noun
                { 
                get {return noun; }
                set {noun = value; }
                }

            public string Adjective 
                {
                get {return adjective;}
                set {adjective = value; }
                }
            public string Panimal
                {
                get {return panimal; }
                set {panimal = value; }
                }

            public string Pnoun
                {
                get {return pnoun; }
                set {pnoun = value; }
                }


            public void InScreen()   
            {        
            Console.WriteLine("First, give me a past tense VERB: ");
            Verb = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nNow, give me a NOUN: ");
            Noun = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nNext, I will need an ADJECTIVE: ");
            Adjective = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nNow, I will need an ANIMAL(plural): ");
            Panimal = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nFinally, I neeed a plural NOUN: ");
            Pnoun = Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

My second class (InsertFunOOUI)

```
        public void Poem()
        {    
         Console.WriteLine("Humpty Dumpty " + **Game.Verb** + "on a " + 
        **Game.Noun** 
          );
         Console.WriteLine("Humpty Dumpty had a " + **Game.Adjective** + " 
        fall" 
          );
         }
```

...you get the picture.

Comment: You need an _instance_ of your `Game` class to access its properties...

Answer (score 1):

`Game` is a Type. A class. You need to create an instance of it:

```
Game g = new Game();
```

and only then use:

```
g.Verb
```

etc.

Comment: see, I tried that...but when creating a new instance it circles back and runs that method over again. I don't get how I'm supposed to instantiate it without it running the same method again.

Comment: I guess I could've explained that too. The Game class is originally instantiated in the Main method. Once it runs, it's handed over to the InsertFunOOUI Class. Which is where I need access to the properties.

Comment: The line `Game g = new Game();` should be called only once. In `Main` according to your comment. Then that instance needs to be passed on to `InsertFunOOUI` and should be used there. Actually that is what you wrote in your last comment. That _should_ work.

Comment: I appreciate you responding. Yes, that is what I did. But because it's already called in Main, and then passed to another Class and called again, it runs twice. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MichaelM `and called again` - what do you mean by that? And did you remember to change all `Game`'s in `Poem()` to `g`'s (or whatever the variable name is that you're using)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an instance of Game in order to use it, unless it you intended for it to be a static class.

```
 Game game = new Game();
 game.InScreen();
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

First create an instance of your game like @ispiro said. You need to do this once (in the main if possible). Then create an instance of your class poem. Use dependency injection and pass the properties of the game object in as parameters instead of the whole object if possible. I would even create a method inside your Poem class that handles the Console Output. Adapt this code to your liking:

```
public void main()
{
    var game = new Game();
    var poem = new Poem();
    poem.Output(game.Verb, game.Adjective);
}

public class Poem()
{
    public void Output(string verb, string adjective)
    {
        // your console writeline code
    }
}
```